# Decoding data sent through a TCP socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, pickle

I have a basic program where in a Tkinter window a user presses a button that generates a string in a listbox. Using a second send button, I want to transfer those strings through a socket server to a second client. The message printed to the console at the point of departure (client1) is a tuple, and it can be iterated through with a for loop to make it more legible i.e. each element is printed to a new line. Using a print function at the point of arrival (client2), the same tuple is produced, but trying to use a for loop on it iterates through each character in the group of strings, as opposed to each element of the tuple as desired.

This is client1:

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import os
import datetime
import pickle


def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break


def send(event=None):  # event is passed by binders.
    global sent
    global current_datetime
    global order_list
    sent = order_list.get(0, END)
    msg = sent
    for i in msg:
        print(i)
    client_socket.send(bytes(str(msg), "utf8"))
    if msg == "{quit}":
        client_socket.close()
        window.quit()
    order_list.delete(0, END)

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Title")
window.geometry("1280x1080")
var = IntVar()
var.set(1)
check_Table_Button = False
font = font.Font(family="Arial", size=9, weight="bold")
height = 4
width = 7
padx = 8
pady = 1
order_list=Listbox(window, width=35, height = 35)
order_list.config(font=font)
order_list.grid(row =0, column = 11, columnspan=3, rowspan=8)

def clickedTable(table):
    # print(table)
    order_list.insert(END, table)
    global check_Table_Button
    check_Table_Button = True

def addTable(table, number, x) #Sample Button to generate string
    table = table
    btn_masa_x = Button(window, text=str(table),font=font,
                        bg="orange", fg="black",
                        command=lambda: clickedTable(table),
                        height=height, width=width,
                        padx=padx+1, pady=pady)
    btn_masa_x.grid(column=x, row=number, rowspan=1, columnspan=1)
addTable("Table 1 ", 0, 0)

def send_button():#Second button to send over socket
    send_button =Button(window, text="Send",
                font=font, bg="lime green",
                command=lambda: send(),
                height=height, width=width,
                padx=padx, pady=pady)
    send_button.grid(column=10, row = 8, rowspan=1)
send_button()

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 33000


BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)
receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
window.mainloop()
```

This is the server:

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread


def accept_incoming_connections():
    """Sets up handling for incoming clients."""
    while True:
        client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
        print("%s:%s has connected." % client_address)
        # client.send(bytes("Greetings from the cave! Now type your name and press enter!", "utf8"))
        addresses[client] = client_address
        Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()


def handle_client(client):  # Takes client socket as argument.
    """Handles a single client connection."""

    name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    # welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % name
    # client.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
    msg = "%s has joined the chat!" % name
    # broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    clients[client] = name

while True:
    msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ)
    if msg != bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
        broadcast(msg)
        # broadcast(msg, name + ": ")
    else:
        client.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
        client.close()
        del clients[client]
        broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % name, "utf8"))
        break


def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):  # prefix is for name identification.
    """Broadcasts a message to all the clients."""

    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8") + msg)

clients = {}
addresses = {}

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER.listen(5)
    print("Waiting for connection...")
    ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=accept_incoming_connections)
    ACCEPT_THREAD.start()
    ACCEPT_THREAD.join()
    SERVER.close()
```

And this is client2:

```
from threading import Thread
import tkinter
import pickle



def receive():
    """Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg =client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ)#.decode("utf-8")
            msg = pickle.loads(msg)
            print(msg)
            # msg_list.insert(tkinter.END,msg)
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break


def send(event=None):  # event is passed by binders.
    """Handles sending of messages."""
    msg = my_msg.get()
    my_msg.set("")  # Clears input field.
    client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    if msg == "{quit}":
        client_socket.close()
        top.quit()


def on_closing(event=None):
    """This function is to be called when the window is closed."""
    my_msg.set("{quit}")
    send()

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Chatter")

messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()  # For the messages to be sent.
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)  # To navigate through past messages.
# Following will contain the messages.

msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(top,width=40,height=10)
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
messages_frame.pack()

entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
send_button.pack()

top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

#----Now comes the sockets part----
# HOST = input('Enter host: ')
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
# PORT = input('Enter port: ')
PORT = 33000
if not PORT:
    PORT = 33000
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)

BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

As I said above, the msg variable in client2, the one that receives the message, is printed as a tuple but a for loop will iterate over each character of the strings contained.

Using the pickle module I received two separate errors.

When I pass .decode("utf-8) and then .loads() it says "Could not find MARK).
Without the .decode(), the error is "unpickling stack underflow".

My desired outcome is for each of the individual strings that arrive over the TCP socket to be added to the listbox in client2  on a new line, and without the ('', '') symbols.

Should I try to convert it to a .json object?
Or will another networking module produce better results?

I'm sorry about the length of code and the potentially obvious answer. Beginner to networking.